# JavaScript - Condicional if else

Tags: javascript, if, else, formatação-condicional

Estou pondo em prática a última aula que fiz de JavaScript e me deparei com um erro em um código que escrevi no VSCode.
Acredito que seja referente a comparação de numeros de dois digitos com números de 1 digito.
Quando comparei o número 9 com o 10, ele volta com o if, ao invés do else if. Isso só acontece com o uso do input através do 'readline-sync'.

Alguém teria uma solução e explicação.

Agradeço!

Exemplo:

```
import teste from 'readline-sync'

let num1 = teste.question("Digite um numero: ")
console.log(num1)

let num2 = teste.question("Digite outro numero: ")
console.log(num2)

if (num1 > num2) {
console.log(num1 + " é maior que " + num2)
}

else if (num1 < num2) {
console.log(num1 + " é menor que " + num2)
}

else {
console.log(num1 + " é igual ao " + num2)
}
```

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque você está comparando strings. Converta as entradas em numérico antes de as comparar.

Comment: Então...foi isso que me veio a mente, por que o VSCode me diz que string, mas eu não sei como fazer essa conversão de tipos, ainda. Grato pela resposta!

Comment: Esse conflito ocorre pq readline-sync usa a função Number() que transforma os inputs  um número e quando comparado um número de 1 dígito com um de 2 dígitos. ficando assim 9 para 9.0, tente substituir para `parseInt(teste.question("Digite um numero: "))`

Answer (score -2):

Use o parseInt para converter as string em inteiros

segue exemplo:

var numInt = parseInt(num1);
var numInt2 = parseInt(num2);

E ai depois e so fazer os If.